# saving an animated gif in iphone

Tags: iphone, animated-gif

In an iPhone, when i open a gif animation in safari and tap on it long enough, then I get an option to save it in the photo gallery, right?
On doing so, is the whole gif file (i.e. the bunch of images bundled together in the gif file) or only the first frame of the bundle saved?
I  converted the saved image into NSData and saw that the data was pretty less too. So does it mean that only the first frame is saved???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to try this would be to copy your gif file to the computer again and see if it animates ;) if not, then you can say that something happened when saving it to your iPhone.

Comment: :P nice...I did something analogous to what you suggested! I am actually trying it in the simulator. I used ALAsset framework to save an image (gif) to the photo library. After saving I accessed the file in the DCIM folder and opened it in the browser and Voila!...the unanimated gif! So I might as well assume that only the first frame is saved somehow. I might be wrong...if someone finds something contradictory, please do share because I'm really wishing the whole animated gif is saved...